# how to add an NSString variable values into an NSString array in Swift ? (iOS )

Tags: swift, xcode6, ios8.1

how to add an string variable values into an string array in swift ? After assigning whole values i want to populate these array elements into an UITableView.

```
[ArrayName abbObject:Stringname]; //objective-c code
```

swift code ?

this objective-c statement to be converted into swift. The value will change dynamically. At these time whole value to be inserted into array and it can be retrieved for further use -thank you

Comment: this objective-c code isn't correct. Also you have to show us your attempts

Comment: @ChristianWoerz woerz Excuse me, i didn't understand the wrong in that code. That code works  fine in the case of Objective-C for me

Comment: It should be addObject

Comment: ok thanks for your information. Actually it just an spelling mistake. Even the compiler will show the error and auto correction suggestions.

Comment: think this is covered in "A Swift Tour" on one of the first few pages of the Swift book. Did you consult any basic introduction to Swift before posting this question?

Comment: @MaxMacLeod no actually i was in a hurry to get the solution. After some try i got the solution without any reference -thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add object to an array string using the following code

syntax:     array_name.append.(var_name)

example:

```
    var peri: [NSString] = []
    var per : NSString = "\(peripheral.name)"
    peri.append(per)
```

In the above case "peri" is a string array, "per" is a string variable and append is keyword used to append the values into the array

Answer (score 2):

You can use the append function. Here's what you should do:

```
var a:[NSString]=[]
var for:NSString="for"
a.append(for)
```

Comment: Great answer ! plus 1

Comment: Wth hell mohit. Come on Facebook.

Comment: i posted this answer 30 mins back. Good  Morning :)

Comment: It would be really nice if you could up vote some of my answers too. :)